# HR-latch flip flop

Tags: flipflop

How can I find the truth table of this HR-latch?
[image]

Comment: Google? Logic thinking? Can you find the TT when that one inverter is not present?

Comment: if I could find it in google, I will not post it her :)

Comment: HR FF?? Never heard of it.. Some exercise-specific beast.

Comment: First hit: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=latch+truth+table&espv=2&biw=1200&bih=914&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjggr_Z3YzQAhUHnRoKHeKkD7sQ_AUIBigB and by the way, without the gate outputs being inverted your circuit won't work so it's a -1 for effort.

Comment: @Andyaka there's a twist in the question: one gate is a OR, the other is a AND. This doesn't show up in a google search... Maybe because it isn't actually very useful, I don't know.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry it's just HR-latch not FF

Comment: @dim - good point - it is actually a latch!!

Answer (score 2):

To compensate for my blindness here's a partial truth table: -

[image]

Please note that you have to invert R (and Q) to realize the actual truth table in the question.

Picture stolen from [here](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Flip-flop_(electronics))!

Now that I've studied it a bit more I can see that it is derived from a the standard NAND latch: -

[image]

If you apply De Morgan's rule to the top NAND you get this: -

[image]

So, the TT is very close to that of a NAND latch.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**.R--H--Q--P.**

> 0--0--0--1... if H=0 then SET P=1 and this is latched even if H=0 to 1
>
> 0--1--x--x... inputs are inactive and QP have latched previous states
>
> 1--0--1--1... if R=1 then SET Q=1 and this is latched even if R=1 to 0
>
> 1--1--1--0...

So it is simply a variation of an SR latch with one active low input=H and one active high input=R

> and that's the Truth Table for an asynchronous Flip Flop or "Latch"